# How to switch between users in OpenWrt using 'su -l' in terminal or any other way?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, openwrt

I have created one new user according to this link "https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/secure.access" and followed the Method 2. I want to switch from root to new user in OpenWrt as I did in Ubuntu [in Ubuntu using 'su -l dhaka(username)' to switch from rafsan to dhaka user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OFHq.png). But the OpenWrt prompts "'su' is not found" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use `su`, the [shadow](https://github.com/openwrt/packages/tree/lede-17.01/utils/shadow) package needs to be installed.

```
opkg install shadow
```

Answer (score 8):

To avoid installing extra packages, shadow-su is sufficient:

```
opkg install shadow-su
```